# Como imprimir las sub-cadenas de una cadena

Tags: c++, string

Digamos ques tengo una cadena de caracteres que en su interior contiene 'mario' y lo que no logro hacer es que sacar las subcadenas de la cadena principal, ***ejemplo: m, ma, mar, mari, mario.***
este es el codigo que he estado desarrollando pero no he podido avanzar mas.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void Subcadenas(char * C);

int main(){
char A[100];
cout<<"Ingrese una cadena de caracteres: ";
cin.getline(A,99,'\n');
Subcadenas(A);
return 0;}

void Subcadenas(char * C){
//Cuerpo de la funcion subcadena
int tam=strlen(C);
int b=0;
char cadena[100];
for(int i=0; i<tam; i++){

}}
```

Comment: Por lo que veos no has intentado nada realmente :// ... ¿Con *sacar subcadenas* te refieres a mostrarlas por pantalla o qué?

Comment: Si imprimir en pantalla las sub cadenas de la cadena principal. no he podido avanzar de esa parte por eso no tengo mucho codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al usar funciones prototipos solo es necesario que especifiques el tipo de dato que ingresara luego, en este caso me apoye con un do-while para la impresión.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    using namespace std;
    void Subcadenas(char *);
    int main(){
    char A[100];
    cout<<"Ingrese una cadena de caracteres: ";
    cin.getline(A,99,'\n');
    Subcadenas(A);
    return 0;
}
void Subcadenas(char *C){
    //Cuerpo de la funcion subcadena
    int tam=strlen(C);
    int b=0;
    char cadena[100];
    do{
        for(int i=0;i<b+1;i++){
            cout << C[i];
        }
        cout << "\n";
        b++;
    }while(b<tam);
}
```